# Handle GIO pin interrupt of TelosB with Contiki-OS

Tags: interrupt, msp430, contiki, sky

I am trying to read an external button interrupt in Telosb. I am using GIO2 to read the interrupt, and it works quite nice with polling techniques, but I am looking something closer to an actual interrupt method.

Referring to TinyOS, there was a HplMsp430Interrupt interface that one could implement for that purpose. I cannot find something similar in Contiki-OS.

Changing pin status does not seem to fire any events, as `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT`does not respond.

Answer (score 1):

A driver for the button on TelosB is already implemented in Contiki. There is no need to work at the interrupt handler level to use it, just call the Contiki API:

```
#include "dev/button-sensor.h" 

PROCESS_THREAD(app_Process, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    SENSORS_ACTIVATE(button_sensor);

    for(;;) {
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();
        if (ev == sensors_event && data == &button_sensor) {
            puts("button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

If you're talking about something else and actually need to implement you own interrupt handler, then Contiki will not help you much. For some Contiki platforms there are macros or functions for controlling GPIO pins, but not for `msp430`. So you just need to use the I/O port interface from the compiler headers, and declare interrupt handler functions with `ISR(PORT_NUMBER, function_name)`, where `PORT_NUMBER` is `PORT1` or `PORT2` (a port that supports interrupt handlers).

See `contiki/cpu/msp430/button.c` for an example how the TelosB button interrupt handler is implemented, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I have already checked the button sensor implementation, which is quite easy to learn and use, but it does not help with my case, as I need to be notified of an external voltage change/interrupt in a GIO pin. Thanks for the port interface mention, I will check it out.